# ElasticSearch | The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm learning ElasticSearch (hosted on AWS). 
I'm using [the javascript sdk](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js-legacy) and [this connectionClass](https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es#readme).

My code:

```
let es = require('elasticsearch');
let client = new es.Client({
  hosts: ['https://search-nboardelastic-xxyy.foo.es.amazonaws.com'],
  connectionClass: require('http-aws-es')
});

function handler() {
  let params = {
    index: 'product',
    q: 'bar'
  };
  client.search(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error ', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Data ', data);
    }
  })
}

handler();
```

**Problem**:
When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Error: Request error, retrying
  POST https://https://search-nboardelasticxxyy.foo.es.amazonaws.com/product/_search => The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView
at checkRespForFailure (/Users/oscarandersen/WebstormProjects/peego/lambda/indexElasticSearch/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:18)
      at done (/Users/oscarandersen/WebstormProjects/peego/lambda/indexElasticSearch/node_modules/http-aws-es/connector.js:48:7)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:11)
      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
      at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

I cant figure out what the problem is, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the error message, I think you should remove `https://` from the hosts parameter.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure how useful this answer will be to you 4 months later but I ran into the same problem and the solution was to set the region for the AWS sdk. There are a number of approaches to this, the one I used was pulling in the aws-sdk to my server.js file and adding `AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-2" });`

Comment: Thank you. That ranks pretty high on the scale of poor error messages

Comment: Thank you Ben, your answer saved my day!

Comment: Ben, thank you so much man! You are awesome!

Comment: Ben..and another thankyou from here.. brilliant find.. and yep.. another rabbit hole of an error message

Comment: Ben.. not all heroes wear capes.